# Did AMP JS updates break the ON attribute?

Tags: amp-html

Our local dev instance of our new AMP HTML site was going smoothly until today. Our Firebase instance was last updated May 23, but today both our local site and hosted site both have issues with the ON attribute:

```
on="tap:AMP.navigateTo(url='https://my_url')"
```

No button element with the ON attribute will fire, and the error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at Ga (string.js:79)
at nk.f.handleAmpTarget (resources-impl.js:1513)
at Kg (v0.js:158)
at l (v0.js:157)
at v0.js:157
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at Jg (v0.js:157)
at Fg.f.trigger (event-helper.js:66)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (priority-queue.js:99)
```

Am I stuck waiting for Google's AMP team to fix this or is there something I can do?

Comment: The given snippet of code seems not related to the error. Can you check if this is related to [this bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/46939)?

Answer (score 0):

It was confirmed that changes to the AMP JS broke the navigation function. This has been fixed.
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/15695